# Uncaught ReferenceError: changePhone is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text inputs on my site for phone numbers. I want to keep all numbers in one format not some like 123-456-7890 and others 1234567890. I've tried writing a code to change this but it is giving me an error of Uncaught ReferenceError: changePhone is not defined.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="phone" onblur="changePhone(this.id)">

function changePhone(id){   
 $(id).text(function(i, number) {
        number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
        return number;
    });
}
```

When running validation my code checks out as valid so I am not understanding why it doesn't work.

On a side note: Is there a PHP solution to achieve this or is jquery my best option?

EDIT: Here is a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/4uk9hhtc/

Comment: not sure if it relates, but does your function definition comes before?

Comment: I've been editing it on jsfiddle so it depends on their format, BUT i did try it on my site with the jquery before the input and it still didn't work.

Comment: Why are you passing `this.id` when there is no id? Also, can you create a jsFiddle.net example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Check my update. I added a jsFiddle

Comment: "Is there a PHP solution to achieve this or is jquery my best option?" - you will need php, if you want server-side validation (javascript validation can be easily bypassed)....

Comment: Updated code from class to id(didn't notice that before) and still not working.

Comment: It's not necessarily validation, but formatting.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this. `$(id)` does not work because you need a `#` before ID. The `.text()` does not work because you are running on an input element. Your fiddle is missing jquery, and the code should in `<head>` http://jsfiddle.net/4uk9hhtc/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that actually works

```js
$(function() {
  $('#phone').on('blur', function(){
    var val = ""+this.value;
    this.value = val.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone" />
```

Pure JS with inline invocation

```js
function changePhone(field) {
  var val = ""+field.value;
  field.value = val.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" onblur="changePhone(this)"/>
```

Comment: Hope the down vote was not some kind of vendetta vote

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong with this.

`$(id)` does not work because you need a # before ID. You are doing `$('whateverID')` should be `$('#whateverID')`

The `.text()`does not work because you are running on an input element.

Your fiddle is missing jquery, and the code should in `<head>`

http://jsfiddle.net/4uk9hhtc/13

```
function changePhone(id){   
    var number = $("#"+id).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
    alert( number )
}
```

OR you could just use jquery and get rid of inline onclick like in the other answers

Comment: @mplungjan what does not work? I enter 10 digits and it comes out 111-1111-111

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, I tested in FF and chrome and both works. I alerted so it's easier for the OP to see the result. 111-111-1111 not 3-4-3

Comment: I am also on OS X, maybe your chrome isn't up to date or something but there is nothing wrong with it. If you can see why it would not work then I am all ears

Comment: Well, then let me know what needs to be changed because I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: Feel free to vote mine up too - someone voted me down without giving any reason

Answer (score 0):

Pure jQuery solution. Your fiddle isn't including jQuery by the way. I'm making assumptions that you know how to include jQuery correctly. You should be using `val()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/2kLywwpu/1/

```
<input type="text" class="phone" id="theText">
```

using

```
var textbox = $('#theText').on('blur', function(){
    textbox.val(function(i, number) {
         number = number.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
         return number;
     });
});
```

Here's a fiddle that's not using your regular expression so you can see that the basic functionality works.
http://jsfiddle.net/2kLywwpu/2/

Comment: Updated my fiddle to include jQuery.

Tried yours. Nothing happened on my end. No errors or text change.

Comment: Well I didn't really test your regex, so that might be your next step.

Comment: Also i just realized you were using `text()` instead of `val()`